# PrimeFaces Push and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, jsf, asynchronous, primefaces, push

I have correctly set up a Push server using PrimeFaces p:push component (using a Jetty web server to handle Websockets).
However, the Push mechanism does not work when trying to display an alert upon reception of another thread.

Here some of the code I use:

**JSF** page firing the asynchronous Web Service call:

```
<f:view ...>
<pm:page title="TEST">
   <p:push onmessage="handleMessage" channel="counter" widgetVar="pushEssaisCounter" autoConnect="true" /> 
    <pm:view id="essais-run">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <pm:header title="TEST">
                <f:facet name="right">
                      <pm:commandButton value="Async Call" actionListener="#{AsyncHandler.onRun}" update="erunMessages erunResult" swatch="a" inline="true" icon="check" />
                </f:facet>
            </pm:header>
            <pm:content> ...
```

Backing bean handling the actionListener and forking on a new thread (**AsyncHandler.java**):

```
public void onRun(ActionEvent event) {
  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new EssaiCallable());
}
```

Code executed asynchronously by the new thread (upon reception of **the Web Service response**):

```
private class EssaiCallable implements Callable<CreerEssaiS1F2Response> {

  @Override
  public synchronized CreerEssaiS1F2Response call() throws Exception {
    log.info("ASYNC TEST RESPONSE received!");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().push("counter", 666);
  }
}
```

I have no exception or error when running this code, but the content is just never pushed :-(
Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cagatay Civici's answer from Primefaces Forum ( http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16545 ):

> This doesn't seem to be supported at the moment, Phase II of PrimePush will enabled implementing such stuff I guess. Feedback is welcome. RequestContext push sends data back to client which then forwards it to the push server, so data must go back to the client, in async case it doesn't seem to be the case.

There is also an issue opened: 
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=849